# Why am I getting "Error: Call to a member function end() on null" using Aerys?

Tags: php, amphp

I'm trying to put aerys on top of my cms but getting error. 
As I see the backend returns not null value - #1 in stacktrace but it doesn't reach $resp->end().
I'm stucked trying to get that value to the end().

Code example

```
$router = router()
        ->route("GET", "/exchangews", $websocket)
        ->route('*', '/{resource}/?', function (Aerys\Request $req, Aerys\Response $res, array $route) {

            // copy params and make scalar the single values
            $params = [];
            foreach(($param = yield $req->getAllParams()) as $key => $val){ 
                if(count($val)==1)$params[$key] = array_pop($val);
            }
            $headers = $req->getAllHeaders();

            $bodyProm = Amp\call( function() use($params, $headers, $route){
                try{
                    $lead = new RequestHandler($headers, array_merge($params, $route));
                    $body = $lead->proccess();
                    return $body;
                }catch(\Exception $e){
                    //
                }
            });
            $body = yield $bodyProm;
            // run my application
            $resp->end($body);

            # matched by e.g. /user/rdlowrey/42
            # but not by /user/bwoebi/foo (note the regex requiring digits)
            # $res->end("The user with name {$route['name']} and id {$route['id']} has been requested!");
        });
```

Stack trace:

```
    Error: Call to a member function end() on null in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ingine/index_aerys.php:47
    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Aerys\StandardRequest), Object(Aerys\StandardResponse), Array)
    #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ingine/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Coroutine.php(74): Generator->send('<!DOCTYPE html ...')
    #2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ingine/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Success.php(33): Amp\Coroutine->Amp\{closure}(NULL, Array)
....
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You're defining `$resp` anywhere. Is that supposed to be `$res->end()` by chance?

Comment: Also, are you including the Aerys library in the file?

Comment: It doesn't matter what libraries you're using. Basics don't change. You need to include the library and define the variable. Now you might be doing it somewhere else but I don't see it in the code you provided so that's why I'm asking to confirm.

Comment: Criticize me all you want, I'm almost positive you should have `Aerys\Response $resp` in you route function not  `$res`

Comment: Greate! Sorry that I criticised you so much I've spent so much time on this and was very tired of.

Comment: No worries. Just remember everyone on this forum is here to help.

Comment: Ok, thanx again I'll take that into account

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple typo. You define `Aerys\Response $res` as parameter, but then use `$resp` and try to call a function on it, which is undefined. You should enable error reporting during development. PHP should emit a notice for an undefined variable there.

Additionally, your `Amp\call` is unnecessary. You can simply write it as:

```
try {
    $lead = new RequestHandler($headers, array_merge($params, $route));
    $body = yield $lead->proccess();
} catch(\Exception $e){
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for the hint, I've just spent so much time trying to understand the correct syntax